# Regex in SQL Server

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, pattern-matching

I need to search for all records that has some common patter in it. For an example say we have

```
Struts 1.3.0, 
Struts 1.3.1, 
Struts 2.1.0, 
Struts 2.1.1.1
```

Basically some part of the string is common but for some part I can have predefined set of characters.

(For example mentioned above we have "Struts" as static String but next few characters can be 0-9 and . similarly this can be some alphanumeric values too).

How to use regex for this in SQL Server? I know this can be easily done in Java/PHP but how to do it in SQL Server?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx  The manual will answer all your questions.  True Regular expressions do not exist in SQL Server.  LIKE is the best you can do.

Comment: `WHERE table.column LIKE '%Struts [0-9].[0-9].[0-9]%'` is probably the closest you're going to get.  But be warned - like can be very slow.

Comment: String can be any thing 1.2 or 1.2.3 or 1.2.3.4....so seems SQL server will not support it or there is any tweak? If not only option we have is to handle it at Java level.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  `table.column LIKE '%Struts [0-9].[0-9]%'` will match all of those - if you need better resolution you should at least narrow down your results from SQL Server in that way.

Comment: Yes there is no way to implement this in SQL server. Finally we did the processing part in java :(